# Direct Uploading on youtube v3 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way that we can use Direct uploading on youtube as provided by youtube v2 api.

below is example of direct uploading that provided by v2 api

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet?csw=1#Direct_Upload

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801604/Sample-VB-NET-program-using-Google-APIs-for-NET-V

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube Data API V3 provides the capability to upload a video.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Comment: Thank you Mike, this code works for browsers based authentication. we want different way that we uses on v2 direct uploading.

Comment: You authenticate once via the browser. After that the credentials are saved by the Google API v3 .NET library and reused indefinitely without requiring re-authentication. If you want re-authentication, you have to delete the "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user" file in the C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming folder.

Answer (score 0):

Read The Youtube Data API V3 Guide provides the capability to upload a video.

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video`